# Uncaught runtime error when running @tanstack/react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using React.js to run a simple React Query code but I am facing an error.
The code:

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import Axios from "axios"


export const Home = () => {
 const { data } = useQuery(["cat"],() => {
   return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
 
 });

 return (
   <h1>
     HOPE <p>{data?.fact}</p>
   </h1>
 )
}
```

The code above is using the public catfact api to fetch the 'fact' data and display it on screen.

The error:

```
Bad argument type. Starting with v5, only the "Object" form is allowed when calling query related functions.
Please use the error stack to find the culprit call. 
More info here: 

https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/react/guides/migrating-to-v5#supports-a-single-signature-one-object


useBaseQuery@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42203:13
useQuery@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:42265:72
Home@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30:70
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:20001:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23285:17
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24581:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9597:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9641:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:9698:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29562:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28810:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28733:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28706:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:28101:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36113:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36091:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:36328:25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the object parenthesis while calling the useQuery. Since v5 it only supports object format for given parameters.

```js
useQuery({
  queryKey: ["cat"],
  queryFn: () => {
   return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data);
  },
  //...
});
```

Comment: When I add your code and add the query client [because an error throwed up] it still does break and not run, can you run the following code in your machine successfully?

Comment: Can you try adding queryKey in array? Like this queryKey: ["cat"] @Active-leopard-58a51d

Comment: ill try doing that, thanks. would reply if it works

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue as you i changed the code to this and i changed axios import

```
import axios from 'axios';

const {data} =useQuery({
        queryKey: ["cat"],
        queryFn: async () => {
         const res = await axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact");
            return res.data;
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {data} = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["cat"],
  queryFn: () => {
   return Axios.get("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then((res) => res.data.fact);
  },
  //...

});
```